# counting number of observations into a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

I want to create a new column in a dataframe that states the number of observations for a particular group.
I have a surgical procedure (HRG.Code) and multiple consultants who perform this procedure (Consultant.Code) and the length of stay their patients are in for in days.

Using

```
sourceData2$meanvalue<-with(sourceData2,ave(LengthOfStayDays., HRG.Code, Consultant.Code FUN=mean))
```

I can get a new column (meanvalue) that shows the mean length of stay per consultant per procedure. 
This is just what I need.   However, I'd also like to know how many occurances of each procedures each consultant performed as a new column in this same data frame.

How do I generate this number of observations.  There doesn't appear to be a FUN = Observations or FUN = freq capability.

Comment: If it will be easier if you would provide `sourceData2` and show desired output

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
tbl <- table(sourceData2[,3:2]) #gives the frequency of each `procedure` i.e. `HRG.Code` done by every `Consultant.Code`

 tbl
 #          HRG.Code
 #Consultant.Code A B C
 #              A 1 1 0
 #              B 4 2 1
 #              C 0 0 1
 #              D 1 1 1
 #              E 2 0 0

 as.data.frame.matrix(tbl) #converts the `table` to `data.frame`
```

If you want the total `unique` procedures done by each `Consultant.Code` in the long form.

```
with(sourceData2, as.numeric(ave(HRG.Code, Consultant.Code,
                            FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))) 
# [1] 3 3 3 2 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 3 3 3 2
```

#### data

```
sourceData2 <- structure(list(LengthofStayDays = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L), HRG.Code = c("C", "A", "A", 
"B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A"), 
Consultant.Code = c("B", "B", "B", "A", "E", "B", "D", "D", 
"D", "E", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A")), .Names = c("LengthofStayDays", 
"HRG.Code", "Consultant.Code"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```